# Check if app is running, NOT as background process

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have a Python code that needs to check if an executable is running or not, but in some different way. The executable takes some time to start (it shows a loading screen), depending on the speed of the computer itself.

When the executable is clicked, the process of starting it is shown as:
[image]
This takes a few seconds, depending on the computer speed.

According to the Task Manager, this is a background process:
[image]

When the executable is active (the loading screen is gone and the window is shown), the process is shifted from the background process to the Apps-section.
[image]

Now I have code that is able to find out if a certain process is running or not.

```
import psutil as psu
"gom_inspect.exe" in (p.name() for p in psu.process_iter())
```

But this code already states 'True' with the loading screen (as background process), while I need it to be 'True' if the program active and ready to use.

How can Python show 'True' when the executable is in the Apps-section instead of the background process-section?

Please let me know if something isn't clear.

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) get a list of open windows, without background processes. Then check if the title of the application you are looking for is in the list. Assuming the title is "GOM Inspect":

```
from pywinauto import Desktop

windows = Desktop(backend="uia").windows()
"GOM Inspect" in [w.window_text() for w in windows]
```